# PhpStorm encountered issues with debugging Xdebug

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug

This is my php.ini

```ini
zend_extension = xdebug
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.client_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.client_port=611
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
```

My env:

- PHP 8.1.3
- macOS
- PhpStorm 2023.3.2

```
httpServer  cmd   php -S 127.0.0.1:83 -t /path
```

> errro : Remote port: 611, root privileges are required to use it

I'm not sure what the problem is! I've been trying for several days and I'm going crazy.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The answer is right in your error message:

> Remote port: 611, root privileges are required

You can not use port numbers below 1024 on Linux/OSX unless you are root (and you don't want to run programs as root).

It is best to leave `xdebug.client_port` alone, so it uses its default of `9003`. You need to make sure that PhpStorm also uses that port, which it also should do by default.

Comment: change port : 9003 

error: 
Debug client host: unreachable

Port 9003 is busy （Port 9003 specified in settings is busy.Port 60,390 is free and can be used by Xdebug.）

A PhpStorm: unable to receive debug connections 

Discover client host: is OFF

Comment: My mistake, the macOS environment used VPN